# Richardson extrapolation (improve formula)

Tags: numerical-methods, extrapolation

Use Richardson extrapolation to improve the formula 
$$
f''(x) \sim \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}
$$
so that the error is reduced to order $h^4$

I am not sure how to go about doing this problem, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated, thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you add a reference to “Richardson extrapolation”?

Answer (score 2):

Richardson extrapolation is based on the fact that if the time-step is decreased to half then the error goes to $\frac{1}{2^p}$. The formula is second order accurate in $h$.

So we can write

$$
f''(x)=\frac{1}{h^2}\left(f(x+h) -2f(x) + f(x-h) \right) + Kh^2 + O(h^4)
$$

Now we use half the step

$$
f''(x)=\frac{4}{h^2} \left(f(x+\frac{h}{2}) -2f(x) + f(x-\frac{h}{2})\right) + K\frac{h^2}{4} + O(h^4)
$$

Multiply the second equation with $4$ and subtract the first to obtain

$$
f''(x)= \frac{1}{h^2} \left[ 16 \left\{f(x+\frac{h}{2})-2f(x) + f(x-\frac{h}{2})\right\} -\left\{f(x+h) -2f(x) + f(x-h)\right\} \right] + O(h^4)
$$
EDIT: I had started incorrectly by assuming first order. The odd powers cancel out. Hope I got the rest of the math right.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error @cheapeffectivedietpills
Although, it did cross my mind that one wouldn't want to use it for improving by 3 orders. Tunnel vision is the greatest enemy of math, I suppose